# talking to a PHP script using SSL and POST

Tags: iphone, ios

I have this code to send some parameters to a PHP script. In theory, the script should return a TXT output like

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

for ($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++) {

    echo($arrayNumbers[$i] . "\n");
}
```

The output is something like numbers, one per line like

```
13244
23123
23455
... etc.
```

This is the iPhone script I have:

```
    NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&phone=%@&address=%@", name, phone, address];

    // encode the URL with % codes
    NSString *escapedString = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease
        (CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes( NULL,
                                                 (__bridge CFStringRef) myRequestString,
                                                 NULL,
                                                 (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                 kCFStringEncodingUTF8));

    NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[escapedString UTF8String]
                                            length:[escapedString length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                                    initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"https://myserver.com/myScript.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];

   NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
    {
        if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil) {
            NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
            NSLog(@"responseData: %@", content);
        }
        else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil)
            NSLog(@"empty");
        else 
            NSLog(@"error");
    }];
```

The result is always empty. Nothing is downloaded from the server.

What should I check? thanks.

Comment: Have you checked your php script receives the response - e.g. add an email script to that php above and see if it's being reached by your ios code.

Comment: try to `var_dump($_POST)` to check you are receiving data from iphon script

Comment: good idea. I did it now and the script is being reached but all posted variables are empty inside the PHP script...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the beginning of the code to this, and it is now working.

```
NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&phone=%@&address=%@", name, phone, address];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                                initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"https://myserver.com/myscript.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:[myRequestString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

  NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
    {
        if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil) {
            NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
            NSLog(@"responseData: %@", content);
        }
        else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil)
            NSLog(@"empty");
        else 
            NSLog(@"error");
    }];
```